# Generating Custom PDF of records detail page like printable view

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, printable, view

![enter image description here][1]I have been trying following code in my VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccController" renderAs="PDF">
 <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:outputLabel style="font-size:25px; font-style:bold;">{!accountName}</apex:outputLabel>
    <hr/><br/>         
     <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:repeat value="{!lstField}"  var="f">
            <apex:outputField value="{!lstAccount[0][f]}"/>
        </apex:repeat>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Which is showing me fields very random style, which does not look perfect like printable view, is there any way to do this ?

UPDATES:

```
<div class="title">{!ObjectType} - {!account.Name}</div>
 <hr/>
 <table>
      <apex:repeat value="{!lstField}"  var="f">
            <apex:panelGrid columns="4"  border="4" width="100%">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType[SobjectApiName].fields[f].Label}"/>
                       <apex:outputField value="{!lstAccount[0][f]}"/>         
               </apex:panelGrid>
 </apex:repeat>

 </table>
```

![Current Outout ][2]

Comment: You can use HTML tags and basic CSS - here is an [example](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57243/how-to-create-a-visual-force-page-as-a-pdf-report-it-should-be-link-on-the-quot/57246#57246). It is also possible to reference the [labels for the fields dynamically](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_objecttype.htm).

Comment: New Updated code shows me the record in 2 columns, however I changed the Column="4", since I have used only 2 items in it ! Now, I want 2 fields in one row, check out the new Updated Image too.

Comment: You should use your browser's "View Source" to see the HTML generated. You are probably outputting a succession of tables each containing 2 of the 4 columns you want. Personally, I think its easier to stick to the raw HTML for PDF output and just use things like apex:repeat.

Answer (score 1):

See [Best Practices for Rendering a PDF](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm). `<apex: outputField>` is on the list of **Components That Are Unsafe to Use in a PDF**.